Does R packages "WeightIt" calculate stablized weights of generalized propensity score?
I have noticed the package weightIt, I want to do GPS-OLS and get weights to do IPTW, can I Use the following code? By the way, GPS-OLS need stabilized weights,  I have noticed some paper calculate the numerator and denominator to calculate stabilized weights. Does the weight following code calculate  is stabilized weight?
#Balancing covariates with respect to re75 (continuous)
W3 <- weightit(re75 ~ age + educ + married + nodegree + re74,
               data = lalonde, method = "glm", use.kernel = TRUE)
summary(W3)
bal.tab(W3)

